# write a paragraph to a file

Tags: python

Ok this is simple, I want to write a huge paragraph of text to a file. I know I can do

```
f=open("blah.txt",'w')
f.write("blah blah \n")
f.write("bla blah blah ")
f.close()
```

but what is a little more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 3 quote string declaration like so.

```
>>> a = '''blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah'''
>>> print(a)
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 18):

```
f.write("""I’ve got a lovely bunch of coconuts
There they are all standing in a row
Big ones, small ones, some as big as your head
Give them a twist a flick of the wrist
That’s what the showman said""")
```